# Matching ONE specific char then another then a minus ( - )

Tags: java, regex

I'am trying to match the following regex: 
I have a String: `F-F-W-F`
i need to write a regex, that checks if the first char is a W or F followed by an - . To check the String `F-F-W-F`.

This is what i came up with:

```
if(SBAKTIV.matches("[WF]{1}-[WF]{1}-[WF]{1}-[WF]{1}")) {
        SBAKTIVMessageForLog = "SBAKTIV: Okay";
        return true;
```

Comment: Are you only looking for the first two characters, or for all four blocks? If the latter, is it always four blocks?

Comment: The String i have to check is ALWAYS F-W-F-W ( W and F can be swapped)

Comment: If it's always that, why bother checking it :)

Comment: Your regex is correct, if you want to make shorter you can use : [`([WF]-){3}[WF]`](https://regex101.com/r/aa9Qic/1/) if you are not sure about the length you can use `([WF]-)*[WF]`

Comment: Well i have to check IF the String is : W-F-W-F ..

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50025067/edit) your question to show us 3 or 4 correct inputs and 3 or 4 wrong inputs ? it will make things clearer

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, your regex is good to go. Or perhaps can be shortened to `([WF]-)*[WF]` or `([WF]-){3}[WF]`.

I'm only posting an answer to provide a non-regex based solution*, in case you end up wanting/needing one of those too:

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        if (word.charAt(i) != 'F' && word.charAt(i) != 'W') {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (word.charAt(i) != '-') {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/1wNhYU)

<sub>*This is based obviously on the length being ok, not null and so on</sub>